# Error: Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Tags: arrays, swift, append, locale

I'm trying to define append values to an array within a Struct however I get the below error:

> Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

I have define a structure for my functions:

```
struct Functions {
    //CURRENCY FORMATTING
```

I'm using the below code to create an array of localeIdentifiers and corresponding description:

```
let localeSheet: [(id: String, name: String)] = {
    Locale.availableIdentifiers.map {
        (id: $0, name: (NSLocale.current as NSLocale).displayName(forKey: .identifier, value: $0) ?? "-")
    }.sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
}()
```

I have defined an array:

```
var localeIdentifiersX = [String]()
```

And now trying to append values to that array:

```
func currencyFormatters() {
    ForEach(0 ..< localeSheet.count) {
            localeIdentifiersX.append(localeSheet[$0].id)
            //print(localeSheet[$0].id)
    }
}
```

This is where the error is displayed.

Thank you

Comment: Think I found what the issue is. But now to figure away around it. ForEach statement is a type of view... need another way to iterate through localeSheet.

Comment: That's a simple one liner `localeIdentifiersX = localeSheet.map(\.id)`

Answer (score 1):

`ForEach` (with capital `F`) is a view builder and its body must return a `View`.

If  you insist on using `foreach` you should do it like:

```
func currencyFormatters() {
    (0 ..< localeSheet.count).forEach {
        localeIdentifiersX.append(localeSheet[$0].id)
        //print(localeSheet[$0].id)
    }
}
```

Also, you can convert all elements of an array to another format at  once with the `map` function like:

```
let localeIdentifiersX = localeSheet.map { $0.id }
```

And then use the result to build your SwiftUI's view.

Comment: This is the reason for the error.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks again.

I mapped as per suggested:
That's a simple one liner localeIdentifiersX = localeSheet.map(.id)

Also used a standard for loop to iterate through the arrays for further processing.